# Is there a way that javascript reads its own variables and generates datalayer variables via GTM scripts only?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

```
<script>
    dataLayer = [{
      'pageCategory': 'signup',
      'visitorType': 'high-value'
    }];
</script>
```

Comment: I have two requirements.
1. The conversion of existing variables to google format datalayer variables.
2. The script for conversion should be fired by google tag manager.
I know DOM parsing could be potential way, but its a dirty method of doing it.

Comment: Hey Sanjoy, can you describe the scenario that you are envisioning? Are you wanting to know if you can create a Custom HTML GTM Tag that reads JavaScript variables and adds them to the GTM Data Layer?

Comment: Yes you  got it right. I have seen AirAsia website does it, just wondering how would have they done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GTM variable that reads a global JavaScript variable on your page, yes.  Then you can use that GTM variable in a custom HTML tag to push to the dataLayer.  Make sure it also fires a "im-ready" event too though, so any dependent tags can wait for it to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to do it. Create a "Custom HTML tag" and insert in it:

```
<script>
    dataLayer.push("documentTitle", document.title);
    dataLayer.push("event", "documentTitleReady");
</script>
```

Now you can use this event to fire another tag that reads this dataLayer variable.